# Browscap.ini missing

Tags: php, browscap

I'm new to PHP, I'm leraning on my own and I'm trying to use the get_browser() function, but I checked in my phpinfo() and it seems I don't have it, because it says "no value". Could you please help me setting up one, or downloading one I can use? Thanks a lot! I looked one in the php site, but it says they are developing one now.

Comment: "browscap.ini download" ask google about it (and always ask google when you have some question before you ask it here)

Answer (score 8):

You can get an updated browscap.ini file here: http://browscap.org/ - choose the version you need (PHP, in this case).

Comment: There's also a userland replacement for `get_browser()` hosted on GitHub for those who enjoy being able to peek under the covers: https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php